# Need Longer Dishwasher Drain Hose

Tags: drain, dishwasher

I have a drain hose that came with my new dishwasher but it's not long enough to reach the disposal. I've tried contacting Samsung themselves and they only have the 6' one that's too short. What are my options for getting a longer hose? My model number is DW80K7050US

Comment: Longer drain hoses and hose extensions are commonly available. Take yours to your local hardware store for end fitting matching.

Comment: I've called around and they either come in a specific size or say they're for a specific brand/model.

Comment: Does your jurisdiction require an air gap? Even if it doesn't, that might help the hose reach.

Answer (score 2):

If you cant find the specific hose, find a hose with the same diameter and use a radiator clamp to tighten it down.  Lowe's or your local hardware store should have something close to what you're needing.  Just have them cut it to the desired length.  Just an option,  hope it helps.